# How would I draw 4 squares in a vertical stack move back and forth?

Tags: java, processing

How would I draw 4 squares in a vertical stack move back and forth using a loop to avoid repeating the same code 4 times when drawing 4 squares. The squares should move as one and when any of them hit the edge of the window, all of them change direction.

```
float location;
float sizeWidth;
float sizeHeight;
float direction;
boolean moving;

void setup() {
  size (1280, 720);
  location = 0;
  direction = height/720;
  sizeWidth = 90;
  sizeHeight = 90;
  moving = true;
}

void draw() {

  background(255);

  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(1);

  for (int i = 0; i < width; i = i + 90) {
    line(0, i, 1280, i);
    line(i, 0, i, 720);
  }

  fill (255, 147, 79);
  int steppedPos = (int)(location/sizeHeight+0.5);
  rect(0, steppedPos*sizeHeight, sizeWidth, sizeHeight);


  if (moving) {
    location = location + direction;
    if (location + sizeHeight > height || location < 0){
      direction = direction * -1;
      location = location + direction;
    }
  }
}



void keyPressed() {
  if (key == ' ') {
    moving = !moving;
  }
}
```

Comment: By [tag:process] DYM [tag:processing]?

Answer (score 2):

Create a [`class`](https://processing.org/reference/class.html) `Square` rather than the single variables `location`, `sizeWidth`, `sizeHeight` and `direction`:

```java
class Square {
    float locationX;
    float locationY;
    float sizeWidth;
    float sizeHeight;
    float direction;
    color col;

    Square(float x, float y, float w, float h, float d, color c) {
        locationX = x;
        locationY = y;
        sizeWidth = w;
        sizeHeight = h;
        direction = d;
        col = c;
    }

    // [...]
}
```

Add an array variable for the squares:

```java
Square squares[];
```

Create the squares in a [`for`-loop](https://processing.org/reference/for.html):

```java
void setup() {
    // [...]

    squares = new Square[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < squares.length; ++i ) {
        squares[i] = new Square(i*90, 0, 90, 90, height/720, color(255, 147, 79));
    }
}
```

Add a method which can draw a Square object:

```java
class Square {
    // [...]
    void Draw() {
        fill(col);
        int steppedPosX = (int)(locationX/sizeWidth+0.5);
        int steppedPosY = (int)(locationY/sizeHeight+0.5);
        rect(steppedPosX*sizeWidth, steppedPosY*sizeHeight, sizeWidth, sizeHeight);
    }
}
```

Draw the squares in a loop:

```java
void draw() {
    // [...]

    for (int i = 0; i < squares.length; ++i ) {
        squares[i].Draw();
    }

    // [...]
}
```

Add a method which moves a Square object:

```java
class Square {
    // [...]
    void Move() {
        locationY = locationY + direction;
        if (locationY + sizeHeight > height || locationY < 0){
            direction = direction * -1;
            locationY = locationY + direction;
        }
    }
}
```

Move the squares in a loop:

```java
void draw() {
    // [...]

    if (moving) {
        for (int i = 0; i < squares.length; ++i ) {
            squares[i].Move();
        }
    }
}
```

See the example:

```java
class Square {
    float locationX;
    float locationY;
    float sizeWidth;
    float sizeHeight;
    float direction;
    color col;

    Square(float x, float y, float w, float h, float d, color c) {
        locationX = x;
        locationY = y;
        sizeWidth = w;
        sizeHeight = h;
        direction = d;
        col = c;
    }

    void Draw() {
        fill(col);
        int steppedPosX = (int)(locationX/sizeWidth+0.5);
        int steppedPosY = (int)(locationY/sizeHeight+0.5);
        rect(steppedPosX*sizeWidth, steppedPosY*sizeHeight, sizeWidth, sizeHeight);
    }

    void Move() {
        locationY = locationY + direction;
        if (locationY + sizeHeight > height || locationY < 0){
            direction = direction * -1;
            locationY = locationY + direction;
        }
    }
}
```

```java
boolean moving;
Square squares[];

void setup() {
    size (1280, 720);

    squares = new Square[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < squares.length; ++i ) {
        squares[i] = new Square(i*90, 0, 90, 90, height/720, color(255, 147, 79));
    }
    moving = true;
}

void draw() {

    background(255);

    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i = i + 90) {
        line(0, i, 1280, i);
        line(i, 0, i, 720);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < squares.length; ++i ) {
        squares[i].Draw();
    }

    if (moving) {
        for (int i = 0; i < squares.length; ++i ) {
            squares[i].Move();
        }
    }
}

void keyPressed() {
    if (key == ' ') {
        moving = !moving;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out Monday’s lecture!  We covered exactly this.